# Problem of fluid velocity and pressure drop inside a horizontal pipe, and an explanation I found myself

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm a college student majoring in chemical engineering and I was simulating a pipe design using a versatile plant designing and chemical engineering tool, Aspen Plus.

The thing I wanted to ask a question about is, the simulation showed that when there is a pressure drop inside a horizontal pipe due to friction, the velocity of the fluid increases.

And I was provided with a brief explanation that this is because the potential energy of the fluid in the form of pressure is converted to velocity, but I can't understand this concept because while the energy loss of the fluid due to friction is converted to heat, why should the remaining potential energy in the form of pressure be converted to velocity?

While I was writing this question, an idea for the explanation of this occurred in my head, which is 'When the pressure of the fluid drops, although it's from the energy loss from friction, the particles of fluid pushes the microscopic bumps on the wall with less pressure and it makes the fluid able to travel at a higher velocity.'

This seems that it complies with the Bernoulli's equation, considering that the fluid can't move at a slower rate in the farther part of the pipe but can move at a faster rate.

Is this explanation correct? And please add some more details if there are any, if it could improve the understanding of this phenomena.

I think this writing might be a bit disorganized, but thank you for reading, and thank you in advance for the answers that could help me understand this better.

Comment: Is the fluid compressible, like  a gas?

Comment: Does Aspen predict that the velocity increases with axial locations, or time?